# Can't Set "Host:" Header with CURL Request

Tags: php, authentication, curl, header

I am trying to make a CURL request with some basic authentication (through sending an encrypted header). However, when I try to set the `"Host: _"` header, the remote server responds with:

> Bad Request: Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.

Here's the code that makes the CURL call. Note that it works as soon as I comment out the `"Host: url"` header in the `$http_header` variable. However, it is used on the target server as part of the authentication procedure, so I can not simply remove it.

```
    $curl = curl_init();

    $opt = array(
        CURLOPT_URL=>$url,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER=>1,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER=>$http_header,
        CURLOPT_POST=>1,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS=>$data_params,
        CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT=>5, // Timeout to 5 seconds
    );
    curl_setopt_array($curl, $opt);

    // $output contains the output string
    $output = curl_exec($curl);

    // it closes the session
    curl_close($curl);
```

The contents of `$http_header` (an associative array):

```
array
  0 => string 'Host: http://localhost/work/myproject'
  1 => string 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data'
  2 => string 'X-Authorization: Basicauth Z2xZjA2YzJhMzIxYTI1ZmIzZTgxYQ=='
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Host` header doesn't accept a full URL, but only a hostname.

In this case the solution is to replace this header:

```
"Host: $url"
```

with:

```
"Host: ". parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST) ."
```

Answer (score 2):

The `Host` header takes a hostname, not a URL. i.e. `localhost`, not `http://localhost/work/myproject`.

cURL should be generating it automatically from `CURLOPT_URL` though.

Answer (score 1):

The `Host` header should not contain the protocol, only the host's name. So in this case all you need is `localhost`:

```
'Host: localhost'
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think either answer answers the asker's question. I've ran into the same problem. From looking at what cURL is sending, it is sending it's own Host header. This means that when you add one you now have two. All servers MUST respond with a 400 error when they see more than one host header.

The trick is get cURL not to generate it's own header (which I haven't figured out how to do yet) or don't send yours. In your case it seems not sending yours is fine. But, for what I'm doing, I have to send mine.